# Unable to get the id from innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am using a dropbox box for a particular column in a table. I am trying to fetch the id of the dropbox box.

```
var dropbox = table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML
```

Using this line, I can able to fetch the innerHTML of the dropdown box. It's like this:

```
<select id="relationship1">
    <option value="Father">Father</option>
    <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
    <option value="Son">Son</option>
    <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
    </select>
```

If I try to print `console.log(dropbox.id)`. I am getting `undefined`. So, how do I get the id from innerHTML, which is `relationship1`.

**UPDATE**

```
console.log(dropbox.getAttribute('index'));
```

This also didn't work. Shows `getAttribute is not a function.`

Comment: Simply remove the `.innerHTML`  Use `var dropbox_id = table.rows[r].cells[c].id`

Comment: Didn't work, mate. It displays nothing.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAttribute` is a method that appears on DOM Elements, not strings (not even if the string contains HTML source code).

If you want to get the ID of a select element, then you must first select the *element*:

```
var dropbox = table.rows[r].cells[c].querySelector("select");
```

(I'm assuming the select element is in the cell you picked).